# Installing octave in termux, "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, termux

I am trying to install octave from the "Its Pointless" repository mentioned in the termux [wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management#Community_Repositories). The repository is added successfully as far as I can tell. However, when I try the command `pkg install octave` I get the error "octave Depends openblas" "octave Depends arpack-ng" "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

I have run `dpkg --get-selections | grep held` but it doesn't return anything.

When I try to run `pkg install openblas` it gives the error "openblas Depends libgcc but it is not installable"

When I try to run `pkg install libgcc` it gives the error "package libgcc is not available but is referred to by another package, this may mean the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. However, the following packages replace it: ndk-sysroot"

After searching some more I did `pkg install clang` but I still get the same errors. ndk-sysroot has been installed during installation of clang.

I have done `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get purge` but that did not do anything.

What can I do to fix this problem and install octave on my phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved by itself.

I tried `pkg install octave` again and got a response saying "The repository https://termux.net stable Release is no longer signed."

So I ran the command `bash setup-pointless-repo.sh` again.

And that was it! `pkg install octave` is now working.